# By clicking on the checkboxes in the mat-select the contents are not displayed

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular-reactive-forms

I have developed a select, which contains checkboxes in mat-option. By selecting the desired checkbox a div should be displayed which is bound to the respective option part. But when I click on it, nothing is shown. Without checkboxes my mat-select works fine. Do you know where my error is and how I can solve the problem?

My Code:

HTML

```
<mat-form-field floatLabel="never">
  <mat-select [(value)]="selectedValues" formControlName="dashboardValue" placeholder="Auswählen" multiple>
     <mat-option *ngFor="let dashboardPosition of displayDashboardValues" [value]="dashboardPosition">
         {{ dashboardPosition.viewValue }}
      </mat-option>
   </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

```
<div class="content-flows-in" *ngIf="selectedValues">
<div *ngFor="let selectedValue of selectedValues">
<div *ngIf="selectedValues['valuePositionType'] === 'test1'">Test 1</div>
<div *ngIf="selectedValues['valuePositionType'] === 'test2'">Test 2</div>
<div *ngIf="selectedValues['valuePositionType'] === 'test3'">Test 3</div>
</div>
</div>
```

TS

```
// For the form
  dashboardForm: FormGroup;
  selectedValues: any;

public displayDashboardValues = [
    {value:'position_1', valuePositionType: 'test1', viewValue:'Profit and Loss'},
    {value:'position_2', valuePositionType: 'test2', viewValue:'Cash'},
    {value:'position_3', valuePositionType: 'test3', viewValue:'Balance'},
  ];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `formControl`, you can remove value binding `[(value)]="selectedValues"` and try emitting `selectionChange` event instead

```
<mat-select ... (selectionChange)="handleChange()" ...>
```

If you need you can also pass `$event` to `handleChange()` function:

```
<mat-select ... (selectionChange)="handleChange($event)" ...>
```

Comment: Thanks for your tip, but I solved the problem differently. I changed my code and this is how it works. I packed the output into another <div> and then iterated with *ngFor="let selectedValue of selectedValues".